# Como centrar e trocar a ordem em flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Preciso fazer algo como está na imagem só que não estou conseguindo trocar a ordem da 2ª coluna e centrar o texto e o titulo também não estou conseguindo colocar aquela linha cinza.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.article {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
}

.article img {
  width: 30%;
}

.text {
  justify-content: ;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

  <div class="text">

    <h1 class="title">New: Learn Arabic!</h1>

    <p class="description">We´re celebrating our 7th birthday with the new Arabic course! Now you can learn the world´s top 6 languages on Duolingo. Enjoy!</p>

  </div>
</article>
<article class="article">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

  <div class="text1">
    <h1 class="title">15+ million lessons a day</h1>
    <p class="description">Around the world, Duolingo learners are completing over 15 million lessons every day. That´s amazing! Keep it up!</p>


  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: A linha você pode usar `border-bottom` . Não entendi o problema em centralizar.

Comment: aqui não aparece mas o texto está muito para cima vou por outra imagem

Comment: Ah, centralização **vertical**. Entendi, estava imaginando horizontalmente

Comment: Amigo, eu costumo trabalhar assim, crio as divs e deixo elas com borda para leiautar, depois eu coloco o conteúdo, não entendo o flexbox, você está usando flexbox? Dá um pulo aqui, e tenta primeiro fazer a mesma divisão que você deseja, depois você coloca os textos as imagens e vai ajustando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos aos pontos.

**Centralizando itens**

Para centralizar os itens da *tag* `<article>`, basta utilizar a propriedade `align-items` no seu CSS, dessa forma você poderia escolher como eles serão alinhados na horizontalmente, no seu caso, use o valor `center`.

```
.article {
  align-items: center;
}
```

**Alterar ordem**

Para alterar a ordem dos elementos filhos de um *flexbox*, basta utilizar a propriedade `flex-direction` com o valor `row-reverse`. Isso fará com que os elementos invertam a posição. O que está na direita passa para a esquerda e vice-versa. No seu caso, você pode utilizar a pseudo-classe `::nth-child(even)` para o efeito ser aplicado apenas nos elementos ímpares.

```
article.article:nth-child(even) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

**Adicionando borda**

Há vários modos, optei por utilizar a pseudo-classe `::before`. Com isso, poderei adicionar um elemento para simular essa linha.

```
.article {
  position: relative; /* Evita que o pseudo-elemento ultrapasse a caixa */
}

article.article::before {
    background: red;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

**Exemplo prático**

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.article {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

article.article:nth-child(even) {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

article.article::before {
    background: red;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article img {
  width: 30%;
}

.text {
  justify-content: ;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

  <div class="text">

    <h1 class="title">New: Learn Arabic!</h1>

    <p class="description">We´re celebrating our 7th birthday with the new Arabic course! Now you can learn the world´s top 6 languages on Duolingo. Enjoy!</p>

  </div>
</article>
<article class="article">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

  <div class="text1">
    <h1 class="title">15+ million lessons a day</h1>
    <p class="description">Around the world, Duolingo learners are completing over 15 million lessons every day. That´s amazing! Keep it up!</p>


  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.article {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  /* border: 1px solid #000; */
  
}

img{
  margin: 1rem;
}

.article img {
  width: 30%;
}

.text {
  /*justify-content: ;*/
  margin: 2rem;
}

.titulo{
  text-align: left;
}

.description{
  text-align: justify;
}

hr {
 border: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <hr>
<article class="article">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

  <div class="text">

    <h1 class="titulo">New: Learn Arabic!</h1>

    <p class="description">We´re celebrating our 7th birthday with the new Arabic course! Now you can learn the world´s top 6 languages on Duolingo. Enjoy!</p>

  </div>
 
</article>
  <hr> 
<article class="article">
 
  <div class="text">
    <h1 class="titulo">15+ million lessons a day</h1>
    <p class="description">Around the world, Duolingo learners are completing over 15 million lessons every day. That´s amazing! Keep it up!</p>

  </div>
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/180x180" alt="">

</article>
  <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações no seu código primeiro você estava utilizando uma classe css com nome de uma tag html o title e isso não é recomendado sobre a linha cinza acresentei a tag <hr> e na segunda coluna se entendi direito primeiro você insere o texto e depois a imagem. Em relação a estilização que fiz não ficou idêntica da imagem, ficou bem proxima. espero ter ajudado na sua dúvida.